# Positioning DIV according to an input element

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I want a DIV to be visible when user enters text in INPUT element. I can make this happen with AJAX. But I can not position the DIV absolutely under the INPUT element. I want it to be shown like DROPDOWN list. Contents of DIV changing by user INPUT. I have searched everywhere but could not found anything.
CSS or JS will be useful.
Here is my code:

```
<tr>
    <th align="left">Görevli Olduğu Kurum Kodu (Farklı bir kurumda görevli ise)</th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="gkrm" name="gkrm" value="" onkeyup="AJAXCODE_TO_LOAD_DIV_CONTENT">
        <div id="gkrmlist">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In that code, I want the *gkrmlist* DIV to be shown under the *gkrm* INPUT. But it appears on the right side of INPUT element.

[You can see the image by clicking the link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbrrz.png)
I want to place the DIV in the red circle to the position, shown with green arrow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, on SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set div under input as absolute, you have to add `position: relative` to it's parent. Then `absolute` to div, set `left`, `right`, `top`

```css
.input-container {
  position: relative;
}

.input-container .input-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: calc(100% - 1px);
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
      <th align="left">Görevli Olduğu Kurum Kodu (Farklı bir kurumda görevli ise)</th>
      <td class="input-container">
          <input type="text" id="gkrm" name="gkrm" value="" onkeyup="AJAXCODE_TO_LOAD_DIV_CONTENT">
          <div class="input-dropdown" id="gkrmlist">this is div
          </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is doing what it meant to do. It is centering the div to its parent element, beacuse of that, I accepted this as solution. But I need to center the div to INPUT element not TD. some of my TD elements are larger than the TD, I am using to show the DIV.

Comment: What I want is [link](https://ibb.co/ha7MPb)
Sorry for the second comment. newbie :)

Answer (score 0):

The element with position `"absolute"` positioned itself depending on its first parent element with position `"relative"`.

So it is very necessary to set its parent element's position to `"relative"`.

Here is the HTML and CSS code

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <th align="left">Görevli Olduğu Kurum Kodu (Farklı bir kurumda görevli ise)</th>
    <td class="rel">
        <input type="text" id="gkrm" name="gkrm" value="" onkeyup="AJAXCODE_TO_LOAD_DIV_CONTENT">
        <div id="gkrmlist">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.rel {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}
#gkrmlist {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Enjoy!